# Is Ark: Survival Evolved a couch coop game?

Tags: ps4, ark-survival-evolved

My wife and I love to play coop games. We are considering getting *ARK: Survival evolved*, as we have have heard that it has a couch co-op mode, but we are not 100% sure.

Can someone please confirm that it does in fact support a co-op mode on PS4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, me and my siblings play it all the time on split screen. First you will click host game, change any settings that you want, pick the place, then hit Create Ark. When you do that it will take a few moments to load up the game, then the first player will make his/her character once that happens then the second player can join and make there character.

Note: When the first person is making their character it will have the exact location you want to go on the right side.

Answer (score 5):

There is a local co-op option for two players. [Source](https://www.co-optimus.com/game/3885/playstation-4/ark-survival-evolved.html)

Comment: My wife and I played "single player" Ark on a PS4 in this manner.  Note you will be limited to locally hosted games.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Information gleaned from comments:</sub>

---

In PvE mode, *Ark: Survival Evolved* is very much co-op based.

The gameplay is kinda like Minecraft meets first person shooter but with dinosaurs. It relies heavily on taming & breeding dinosaurs to ease chores and improve your quality of life, but also on crafting and base building.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the question title doesn't specify PS4 people may land here looking for an answer the PC version.

Unfortunately the answer is no, the PC version does not support coop play. To play cooperatively you'll need at least two PCs and screens etc.